# Show a RadDesktopAlert on form

Tags: winforms, telerik, nullreferenceexception

i want to Show a RadDesktopAlert on a form (not on the desktop). therefore i use second constructor to set its container to form. but nullException raised for this.Container
am i in the correct line to show RadDesktopAlert on the form (it is better to say IN THE FORM)?
and why container is null?
here is my code

```
      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDesktopAlert q = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDesktopAlert(this.Container);//null exception: Container is null
        q.ScreenPosition = Telerik.WinControls.UI.AlertScreenPosition.BottomCenter;
        q.ContentText = "what ever";
        q.Show();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need to set the ScreenPosition to Manual and then set the popup location

```
        Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDesktopAlert q = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDesktopAlert();//null exception: Container is null
        q.ScreenPosition = Telerik.WinControls.UI.AlertScreenPosition.Manual;
        q.Popup.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 20, this.Location.Y + 20);
        q.ContentText = "what ever";
        q.Show();
```